# JavaScript string equality seems sporadically broken in Chrome, possibly related to Web Workers?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I have a function in my application that is (for a very small percentage of users, but for a few people every day) raising an error that seems impossible. It looks like, from the error the function raises, `'center' !== 'center'`. Every occurrence of this error happens on Chrome, and the first occurrence was on October 16, 2023. Users run into this error once or twice, then it seems to resolve itself.

Here's a simplified version of the function. There's a lot of code stripped out, but the relevant control flow is almost exactly the same.

```js
function createBaseGradient(gradient) {
    const start = gradient.start;
    
    // ...

    if (start === 'center') {
        // ...
        return '...'
    }

    // ...

    if (start === 'left') {
        // ...
    } else if (start === 'top') {
        // ...
    } else if (start === 'bottom') {
        // ...
    } else if (start === 'right') {
        // ...
    } else {
        internalError(
            `Illegal gradient start (${JSON.stringify(start)}, ${encodeURIComponent(
                start
            )}, ${stringToCharCodes(
                start
            )}) of type ${typeof start}. Webworker: ${isWebWorker}. Valid gradient starts are: (${VALID_STARTS}, ${VALID_STARTS.map(
                stringToCharCodes
            )})`
        );
    }

    // ...

    return '...';
}
```

Here is the exact text of one of the errors I've seen:

> Error: Illegal gradient start ("center", center, 99,101,110,116,101,114,END) of type string. Webworker: false. Valid gradient starts are: (center,left-top,left,left-bottom,top,bottom,right-top,right,right-bottom, 99,101,110,116,101,114,END,108,101,102,116,45,116,111,112,END,108,101,102,116,END,108,101,102,116,45,98,111,116,116,111,109,END,116,111,112,END,98,111,116,116,111,109,END,114,105,103,104,116,45,116,111,112,END,114,105,103,104,116,END,114,105,103,104,116,45,98,111,116,116,111,109,END)

So the constant `start` is a string, with value `"center"`, and all of the characters of the string are the same characters as the characters in the string `"center"`, in the same order. Yet `start === 'center'` can't have been true, because we didn't enter the first if statement and return.

A few more details that may be relevant: The argument `gradient` is created in a web worker before being used in this function. `gradient.start` is converted to a JavaScript string from a Brython string type. And this error does occur for other values of `start`.

Here's what I've tried so far: I added the detailed logging that I included above. I tried storing all strings in the function in constants, and using those constants to create the `VALID_STARTS` array, just in case some browser extension was modifying the strings, but that doesn't seem to be the case. I added more logging, not included above, to throw an error if we somehow entered the `start === 'center'` case and continued without returning, but that error has never triggered.

I also tried to create a minimal example of a possible Web Worker bug (where the string `'abc'` posted from a Web Worker may not equal `'abc'`). I ran it a few million times on my computer, but it never produced an error. The date of the first error doesn't coincide with a new Chrome release or any relevant deploys on my end. I briefly skimmed the open bugs in Chrome, but it didn't seem like I was going to have great luck there.

I'd really appreciate hearing new perspectives on how to tackle this bug, and insights from any JS gurus out there. Could this string not be a string, despite `typeof start` being `'string'`? Could I be accidentally modifying the string prototype and breaking equality somehow? I'm not sure where to look next.

Here's a link to the unedited source code for this function, if it would be helpful to look at: https://pastebin.com/0hdqLjqH

Thanks so much for any ideas you might have!

---

#### New information based on suggestions in the comments:

I logged the following values right before the `if (start == 'center')` if statement. Their results are in comments next to the value.

```
const a = start + '!'; // center!
const b = CENTER + '!!'; // center!!
const f = start == CENTER; // false
const c = start === CENTER; // false
const d = typeof start; // string
const e = start.toString() === CENTER.toString(); // true
const g = start.normalize('NFC') === CENTER.normalize('NFC'); // true
```

So there's progress! It's not clear to me why calling `.toString()` is making a difference, or how normalizing the string makes a difference when we already compared each character code. But we actually have something to go on now.

Comment: Is it at all possible that the control flow within your `if (start === 'center')` block might *not* result in a `return`? This would be extremely strange bug for Chromium to have all of a sudden without having already been reported.

Comment: String comparison is probably 3/4 of the work a JavaScript runtime does, so it's extremely difficult to believe it would be broken in a prominent platform like Chrome/V8.

Comment: Based on your error message, it's because you're comparing the string `"center"` (with the quotation marks included), with the string`center`.

Comment: @daniel Nope, JSON.stringify adds the quotes.

Comment: Ah I see.   That's a bit confusing, why are you stringifying a string?

Comment: Thanks for the replies so far! I'm totally on the same page -- string comparison being broken in V8 sounds very unlikely. I think something more mundane is happening, but at this point I'm not sure what it might be.

Comment: @esqew I don't think it's possible for the `if (start === 'center')` block to not result in a return. I added the full source code for my function to my post, if you'd like to take a look. That also contains some extra logging (which is live now) that would throw an error if we entered that code block and didn't return, but that error never triggers. And the "illegal gradient start" error does continue to trigger.

Comment: @DanielBeck It is weird to stringify a string! I tried `stringify`, `encodeURIComponent`, and finally `stringToCharCodes` in various attempts to suss out invisible characters, weird whitespace, etc.

Comment: Can you try to make this code a [mre] of the issue? For instance, can you include a simplified implementation of `canonicalizeGradientStart()` as well as a sample data structure representative of what you're expecting `fillOrBorder` to look like when passed to this function? I have a hunch that the input object or the return value of that function is not acting in the way you expect. With the current context, I unfortunately cannot reproduce in [this simplified jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/qo2yh3na/).

Comment: In the example in your question, is it possible that `gradient.start` is `undefined`? If `gradient` is a simple Object (i.e., not any sort of class that would implement safeguards/checks against the contents) that may also be a likely culprit.

Comment: Sure thing! I replaced the link in the question -- the new one includes some more detail. I'm also not able to locally reproduce the error myself. And it seems like my users are encountering it sporadically (and those that are, only once or twice). So I'm not able to create a truly reproducible example, just add a little more context.

Comment: Theoretically, `start` or `gradient.start` could be `undefined`. But in this case, the error message is reporting that `start` is the string `"center"`. I haven't seen an instance of the error that would indicate that any of these values are undefined.

Comment: Do `const a = start + '!'; const b = CENTER + '!!'; const c = start === CENTER; const d = typeof start;` directly above the `if` and log `a`, `b`, `c` and `d` in your error as well. (The `+ '!'`/`+ '!!'` parts are in case there _is_ some obscure error in V8 - I don't want the same in-memory string to be reused here.) Would be interesting to see what you get.

Comment: @CherryDT Thanks! Somebody just triggered the error with your suggested logging:

Comment: New logging at the end: `Error: Illegal gradient start ("center", center, 99,101,110,116,101,114,END) of type string. Webworker: false. Valid gradient starts are: (center,left-top,left,left-bottom,top,bottom,right-top,right,right-bottom, 99,101,110,116,101,114,END,108,101,102,116,45,116,111,112,END,108,101,102,116,END,108,101,102,116,45,98,111,116,116,111,109,END,116,111,112,END,98,111,116,116,111,109,END,114,105,103,104,116,45,116,111,112,END,114,105,103,104,116,END,114,105,103,104,116,45,98,111,116,116,111,109,END). a: center!, b: center!!, c: false, d: string`

Crazy!

Comment: i'm no expert, but it might worth to try to log the `start` and `CENTER` variables and `start === CENTER` before `if (start === CENTER) {` line, also maybe try even `start == CENTER` (only double equal), `start === 'center'`, `CENTER === 'center`, at this point we might need to try anything

Comment: @Austin Schick, Please try update your code with start.toString() === 'center'.toString()

Comment: Ok this is extremely weird. I don't know what could be going on. You could work around this, maybe, by using `start.split('').every((c, i) => c === CENTER[i])` (or perhaps even `c.charCodeAt(0) === CENTER.charCodeAt(i))`, but if this happens here, who knows where else it may happen too!

Comment: Can you add the additional insights gained from the comments into your question please?

Comment: You mention Brython. It does not transpile the worker JS code, does it?

Comment: Oh yes that would be very interesting! Can you log `createBaseGradient.toString()`?

Comment: @CherryDT *If* it does mess with the JS, it'll also mess with `Function.prototype.toString`. Really this should be checked by debugging the production app with sourcemaps disabled; or confirmed by statements in the brython docs. The first step is only to check whether the code is affected at all, for any user not necessarily those with the problems.

Comment: This is a strange bug, 

i hope you aren't localizing it in a different language string to compare and then logging the English string in the error. 

Comment: What happens if you use numbers instead of strings? If you don't produce it via numbers, then you can isolate it to something about the string comparison, as you initially thought.

Comment: @Sahab Done, and this is the first comparison that returned true! Any idea why this made a difference?

@CherryDT I added a new section to the question with the new insights we've gotten.

@Bergi Brython doesn't transpile this function. I have looked at the production code with sourcemaps disabled, and though our Webpack setup makes some small changes to it, I don't think anything relevant in `createBaseGradient` itself changes.

Comment: @Austin Schick start.toString() === 'center'.toString() , here === compare value and type strictly

Comment: @AustinSchick You say `const d = typeof start; //# string` but what is `typeof CENTER;` reported as? Knowing that could help others explain why `start === CENTER` is False...

Comment: @AustinSchick After some testing I can see that you will get **type of** as String. See if replacing first line with: `var start = String(gradient.start);` fixes it for your affected users otherwise this might be a Chrome bug (since it magically resolves itself after a while on the same device). Can you provide any info about a typical affected system (_eg:_ is 32/64-bit OS)?

Comment: Downvote for still not having a reproducible test case.

Comment: @Brad - They said they haven't been able to recreate it because it's only happening for some users. @Austin - Is the value coming from the web worker being set by Brython? If so, [its toString implemenation](https://github.com/brython-dev/brython/blob/master/www/src/py_string.js) may be relevant as it seems to be capable of returning it's own custom JS class, which may be why calling `toString` as Sahab suggested had unique results compared to other attempts. Any additional info from users this happens to? Is it consistent, or random; did anyone include their browser version(s)?

Comment: What do we get for `start === 'center'` and `CENTER === 'center'`?

Comment: Can you explain when and how you update the variable in the webworker? It is always dangerous to do something in 2 different threads, without synchronize them. You need to process what you want do in the webworker and signalize it with postMessage. output a string to the console need much time. So it it possible that until you reach this line, the variable is still not set and once you print it out, the variable is set.

Answer (score -4):

The code doesn't even look correct.
Variable can never be the same object === as a constant.
However
Variable can equal == a constant.

```js
var start = prompt("please input one of 'left', 'right', 'bottom', 'top'");
    if (start === 'left') {
      alert("your input was 'left'");
    } else if (start === 'top') {
      alert("your input was 'top'");
    } else if (start === 'bottom') {
      alert("your input was 'bottom'");
    } else if (start === 'right') {
      alert("your input was 'right'");
    } else {
      alert("your input was none of the known options");
    }
```

Comment: Wait for it long text answers are coming.

Comment: "*Variable can never be the same object === as a constant.*" - what? No, it definitely can.

Comment: How can it be the same object as constant in the code.  The exact same object in memory.

Comment: A constant in the code (literal) also just evaluates to a value. That value may be the exact same value, possibly even in the same memory location, as the value that is stored in a variable.

Comment: I updated your code into a runable example. You can clearly see if you enter one of the four values in to prompt box also the `===` comparison will work ... Why? Because of how the [Strict Equality Comparison Algorithm](https://es5.github.io/#x11.9.6) is specified in JS. (For the case of `string` especially look at step 5)

Comment: A string is a "raw" value and every string always "points to the same bit in memory". A variable and a constant can both contain the same value. `const a = {}; var b = a; a === b // is true`, this has nothing to do with the way a variable is created.

Comment: @somethinghere  OP probably is not referring to `const` vs `var` or `let`. But having a string literal like `"center"` in the code

Comment: Which is still unrelated. `"center" === "center"`, `const a = "center";  const b = "center"; b === a // true`. This answer is confused. I know the OP isn't concerned with this, this answer is.

Comment: just change the === to == and see if it goes away.  There was a bounty on this question surely if it wasn't bad code someone would have answered it.  I know its woke code because code doesn't have to be exact to work correctly.  This is nowhere close to my most negative answer.   No worries.  Woke coders.